# How random is Python's Random Module

Tags: algorithms, random-number-generator

Recently i wrote a programme using random module of python. Then i realised that the same output was being repeated quite a number of times though it was supposed to be completely random.

Comment: Actually i have been investigating the programme i wrote up, and i realised that the programme i had written made it easier for some outputs to occur via a better probability.... kindly ignore this question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to understand that all of those libraries/functions won't really give you a truly random number. Why? because whatever algorithm it uses, would be taking input, and performing some predefined steps on it i.e. it is deterministic in nature. So in theory, if you know the exact input and algorithm used to generate random numbers you can replicate it.

Also, the distribution of the random numbers matter, for example, if it is a gaussian distribution, you might find some numbers repeating themselves which are closer to the mean for given range of values. The numbers are repeating themselves because they are generated that way, you might want to try seeding or shuffling to induce more randomness, or try implementing some of the algorithms yourself.

If you really want a truly random number sequence, the input would have to be truly random (variation in the path of Brownian motion, weather patterns, radioactive decay, etc).

You can start by looking at how a Linear congruential generator works. It's pretty easy to notice why numbers would repeat after a point.

Comment: Tidal waves and stock market are not random...

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that. I had read that somehow statistical mechanics could be used to analyse stock markets so I thought that at the quantum scale things would be random but was clueless about the tidal waves.